# Python error while jumping from one link to another. One for loop works , the other doesn't

Tags: python, parsing, networking, beautifulsoup

I am a Python novice.I have two code instances. I am trying to jump from page to page using hyperlinks and extract specific links in the process. I am using BeautifulSoup for parsing. Why does the second one run and the first one doesn't?

#*****Instance 1: Doesn't work....*****#

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


position = int(input("Enter position:"))
count = int(input("Enter count:"))



tags = soup('a')


for x in range(count):
    temp=tags[position-1].get('href', None)
    print(temp)
    html2 = urllib.request.urlopen(temp, context=ctx).read()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
```

#*****Instance 2:Works perfectly....*****#

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


position = int(input("Enter position:"))
count = int(input("Enter count:"))



tags = soup('a')

for x in range(count):
    temp=tags[position-1].get('href', None)
    print(temp)
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(temp, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
```

Comment: How exactly is the second one running at all?  You seem to be referencing html2 before you assign it any values

Comment: Is there a typo in the 2nd one? You are assigning `html = urllib.request.urlopen(temp, context=ctx).read()` but then using `html2` on the next line `soup = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')`. The code is confusing, is it just downloading the same page over and over? You don't use `x` to update an index or anything, you basically run the same loop `count` times